# How perform SSRS URL action without triggering Print Dialog?

Tags: javascript, url, reporting-services

I have several SQL Server Reporting Services reports with text boxes having URL actions that look like this:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://...some-web-site...="
+ Fields!someField.Value
+ "&lang=eng&tab=reg','_blank'))"
```

The URL actions work, but immediately after the web page opens, the browser's Print Dialog opens with a print-to-pdf type option selected.  The user then has to close the Print Dialog in order to view the web page.  How can I stop the browser's Print Dialog from opening when the URL action is performed?

Comment: Is the page the has the Print Dialog a reporting services report?

Comment: @aduguid: I believe that the Print Dialog is coming from the browser web page opened by the URL action, not from the browser web page containing the SSRS report.  The javascript code opens the targeted web page in a separate browser tab.  I think it's fairly commonly used code.

Comment: Does the print dialog open for other urls or just the one you're testing? Have you testing this on other machines? I don't believe it's an issue with the `javascript:void`. I use that a lot and have never had the print dialog open.

Comment: Try testing the javascript with just "google.com" and see if the print dialog opens.

Comment: I duplicated one of my problem reports, and replaced the javascript with this: 
 `="javascript:void(window.open('http://google.com"  + "','_blank'))" `  When I clicked the resultant URL, it correctly opened the `Google.com` web page without opening the Print Dialog.  I get exactly the same behaviour when I use a different machine (i.e. Print Dialog opens when I click the URL on the original report, but no Print Dialog when I click the URL on  the "Google" version of the report).  Makes me think something is wrong with my javascript but I don't see the error.

Comment: I would think the url is the issue

Comment: You are correct.  The problem turned out to be the `Fields!someField.Value` portion of the URL.  The web page expects that value to be a numeric string, but the value I'm passing includes a non-numeric suffix.  The solution is to strip off the suffix when building the URL.  Thanks very much for your help with this.  If you'd like to post your comment(s) as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Well, thought I had this solved, but I haven't.  @aduguid is correct: the url is the problem.  I've posted another question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59260425/why-does-this-url-do-different-things-depending-on-how-its-activated)) in which I've tried to focus more specifically on the particular url that I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try testing the JavaScript with just "google.com" and see if the print dialog opens.

`="javascript:void(window.open('http://google.com" + "','_blank'))"`

Does the print dialog open for other urls or just the one you're testing? Have you testing this on other machines?

Comment: Also see my last comment under my original post.