# Why does this URL do different things depending on how it's activated?

Tags: javascript, url, reporting-services, localhost, window.open

In a related post ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59231683/how-perform-ssrs-url-action-without-triggering-print-dialog)) I discuss a problem I'm having with a URL action in a SQL Server Reporting Services report.  I thought I had solved the problem, but I now realize that I haven't.  (I'll update the related post in due course.)

I'm generating a URL using string concatenation, and using Javascript so the URL opens in a new browser tab.  Here's the code that generates the URL, which I think is pretty standard:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://www.ic.gc.ca/app/opic-cipo/trdmrks/srch/viewTrademark?id="
+ Fields!applicationNoWithExtn.Value
+ "&lang=eng&tab=reg','_blank'))"
```

And here's an example of the URL that's generated when a value is inserted:

```
http://www.ic.gc.ca/app/opic-cipo/trdmrks/srch/viewTrademark?id=159511-00&lang=eng&tab=reg
```

The generated URL works.  It takes you to an online database web page for a Canadian trademark having application number 159511-00 (you don't see the "-00" suffix on the web page, but it's the correct application number).

The problem is that when the user clicks the generated URL, the browser's print dialog opens immediately after the web page opens.  That's very distracting; the user has to click Cancel to dismiss the print dialog.  If the web page is reloaded or refreshed within the browser, the browser's print dialog opens again.  However, if I copy the URL and paste it into a new browser tab, I get the desired web page without the print dialog.  I don't get it; it's the identical URL, but the version of the URL generated by my application somehow triggers the print dialog, whereas a copy/pasted version of the identical URL doesn't.  I've tried different browsers (Chrome, Edge and IE) and different machines, but I keep getting that print dialog when I click the URL generated by my application.  If I change the code to generate a standard URL like http://google.com the generated standard URL works without triggering the print dialog.  So the problem seems to be with the particular web site that I am accessing via the concatenated URLs shown above.

Can anyone explain what's going on and how I can suppress that print dialog?

Comment: I don't understand how you're using the `!` operator in `Fields!applicationNowWithExtn.Value`

Comment: Barmar: The ! Operator is standard syntax for a SQL Server Reporting Services URL action.  The expression quoted in your comment is actually generated by an expression builder that’s part of SSRS.

Comment: But you're using it in the JS code that's concatenating strings, not in the SSRS URL.

Comment: Yes.  That’s what the expression builder returns.  It works except for this print dialog annoyance which I suspect has something to do with the particular web site I’m accessing.

Comment: To the interested parties you can repro but opening the console and calling `window.open('http://www.ic.gc.ca/app/opic-cipo/trdmrks/srch/viewTrademark?id=159511-00&lang=eng&tab=reg', '_blank')` (that's using the example url above)

It does seem they have some `js` on the page that opens the print dialog.

Comment: Confirmed, if you poke around the source there's a `window.print()` call.


$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".detailsimgsize").width( $(".detailsimgsize").width() * 1);
  
  var body = document.querySelector('body');
  $activeTab = $("#details-bio-info");
  tabTo($activeTab);

  if (window.opener) {
    $('.hidden-print').hide();
    $('.vsbl-print').show();
    $("div").removeClass("wb-tabs ignore-session tabpanels");
    $("details").attr("open", "open");
    window.print();
  }
  


});

Edit: I don't know a good way to inline the code here

Comment: @dcchuck:  Thank you **very** much.  I'm out of my depth here.  Can you suggest a workaround?  Maybe a simple piece of javascript I could add to force the print dialog closed so the user doesn't have to click Cancel?  I suppose that might get me into a timing issue though.  I can't understand why that `window.print()` call is in there.  I suppose I could try to contact the web site administrator to see if they'd consider tweaking it, but in this case it's the Canadian federal government.  I don't fancy my chances of getting their attention!

Comment: Because of the way the web works, you won't be able to control anything on that new window once you open it. You could create a page that sets `window.location.href = the_url_you_need`, that doesn't seem to trigger the print. Pass what you need as query params, parse them, and redirect as above. I'm not sure if you're just exposing a db endpoint or are able to serve your own page

Comment: I replaced my javascript (see my OP above) with `="javascript:void(window.location.href = 'http://www.ic.gc.ca/app/opic-cipo/trdmrks/srch/viewTrademark?id="
+ Fields!applicationNoWithExtn.Value
+ "&lang=eng&tab=reg','_blank')"` and it opened the web page *without* the print dialog.  So--progress!  Thank you again.  But now the web page opens in the same tab.  I want it to open in a new tab, which is why I was using `window.open`.  Is there a way to use `window.location.href` *and* have the web page open in a new tab?  As I said, I'm out of my depth here.

Comment: I've noticed something else: the problem only occurs if I'm running on the LocalHost.  However, if I access SSRS over my LAN from another machine I don't get the Print Dialog popup when I click the URL, even with the window.open version of the code.  However, I need to run on the LocalHost, e.g. to do demos on my laptop where everything (SQL Server, SSRS, etc.) is running on the LocalHost/Laptop.  I'm still hoping someone can explain how to fix this.